# How to call non static concrete method of abstract class within the class?

Tags: java

I want to call *non static* concrete method of *abstract* class within the class. Like method `a()` in `main`.

```
public abstract class A {
    public void main(String []args) { }

    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Concrete Method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a *non-static* method from *static* method, you have to *instantiate* the class. But [Abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) classes **cannot be instantiated**.

You should create some class that *extends* `A`, then instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Most times for a class to be abstract, it has to be a super class,if not the class will be useless, then if this abstract class has a concrete method, this method can be called only in a class that inherits(it's subclass) it by calling it with an object of the subclass or by including "super." before the method to show it is a super class.